# ng-token-auth $rootscope.user object changes on page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm getting issues using ng-token-auth with devise-token-auth. Sign in, Sign up and Sign out are working well. But when i refresh the page while a user is signed in, $rootscope.user object gets updated with value of previously signed in user.

When i clear the cookies after each sign out, everything works fine. 
The auth_headers are being updated on each sign in/page refresh.

config.change_headers_on_each_request is also set to true in devise_token_auth.rb.

Comment: Were you able to fix this? I am having the same problem right now.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem (I think). I opened this [issue](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/375) about it and apparently it is related to this [pull request](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/pull/200).